# Some Images show a pink bar on the Side on some Android devices in Shopify. How do I remove it?

Tags: image, shopify, cdn

In my online shop i found that on some android devices (Samsung A52 - Android 13 and others) there is a pink line on the right side of some images. This applies to jpg and png. I suspected that its a Problem with the theme or some Apps. But when I open the image in a new tab, the pink bar is still there.

To rule out the Theme I created a clean version of the theme, without any custom code or app. I uploaded the Image to the theme and it showed up correctly. Then I've put the Shopify cdn Link from the Image with the pink onto the new site. There it showed the pink stripe. Now I could reupload all Images, but only having one phone to check if an image is flawed and with over 300 affected images this would be a ton of work.

Did someone experience something similar? I've seen the pink bar on other shops created with shopify, so it shouldn't be a problem specific with me. Has anyone any Idea on how to fix this easier than spending a whole week replacing the flawed images one-by-one?

Comment: I'm not sure but I suspect this is because of problems with the alpha channel and the way images are set up with CSS in your theme. By default, images are inline-blocked thus creating a small empty space. Try setting up display: block on your img tag. It would be easier if you share the link

Comment: @TwistedOwl Thanks for the reply! I dont think this has anything to do with the css, because when I open the image directly, the pink bar still appears. Here is a Link with one of the Images with this bug: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0572/5909/8282/files/GBA22_VE_GOLD_MC_RGB_220x220.png?v=1677512126

Comment: I don't see any pink color on the image. Can you check different browsers? Maybe this is image format related issue?

Comment: I can't see the color either. It just shows up on the phone of two of my coworkers. Sadly one of them is my boss, so this needs to be fixed, although its just a minor bug that appears on very few android phones. Sadly I don't know the format. When I download the image from the cdn I get a avif with my mac. My Colleague gets a webm with his win. We uploaded a png. I sadly can't tell you wich format is displaying on the Samsung A52

Comment: Google must have broken avif handling starting from Android Chrome 110 on some devices (not all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today Shopify have now confirmed that they have managed to recreate the problem and have agreed that there is an issue with Chrome on Android correctly displaying images. As a result they have changed the Shopify platform so that PNGs are no longer compressed as efficiently as they were when sent as .AVIF, but are sent in the way they used to be. Result is all transparent PNG images render correctly though there will be a tiny impact on page load speeds. The good news is no pink stripes.

I guess at some point they will work out if the problem is with Shopify or with Chrome and once fixed they will start sending the images compressed better as AVIFs.

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers to the same question (unless they are actually distinct solutions, which should be exceedingly rare). Instead [edit] your original answer to include the information you wanted to add here.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem and drove me crazy, I found out that converting the .png to webp (which is good to do anyway), the pink bar are gone !

Comment: this must be marked as an answer, because it is the only sensible way

Answer (score 2):

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1429594

There is a bug report created in chromium

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  As I read it in the Link the issue is related to chrome, not Shopify, right?

Comment: yes, it is a Chrome issue in handling of avif images. Converting them to webp would work (haven't used Shopify, not sure how to replace files there).

Answer (score 0):

We also have a Shopify store and our logo plus other images are also showing the pink strip. The problem was first observed at the end of March and I've been battling with the Shopify support team to get an answer ever since.

What I do know is that the problem is on Chrome bowsers on mobile devices running Android, so desktop and Apple aren't an issue. The problem occurs when the Shopify CDN resizes the original image so that it is a smaller size and loads quickly. However in doing so it may cause the pink strip to appear on the right of the image, but only if it is a transparent PNG and has something that isn't just transparency in the right portion of the image.

The problem also appears to be limited to images that are rendered at full size or close to full size. If an image is scaled at double size to make use of higher pixel density on mobile devices then Chrome will render correctly, but if it is resized at normal size then it will render with pink.

I think the issue is with the Shopify CDN, my guess is about 4 weeks back they put live some changes that used more recent features in the PNG standard with the aim of reducing file size, but inadvertently introduced the problem, though it could be with the way Chrome is rendering the images. Only Shopify or Chrome are going to know the answer to that and I've got tickets out with both.

After a lot of testing what I have found is in the liquid if the img_url tag is used to set the image width to something divisible by 8 then it will render correctly. (If you use a srcset to scale by 2, then it only needs to be divisible by 4 as it doubles to 8). Also images that are output that are small with a width of under around 100 pixels or are large with a width of over 550 pixels appear to render ok irrespective of if they are divisible by 8.

Really Shopify need to fix this as most users aren't going to be messing around changing the liquid. It doesn't matter what size the original image is uploaded as it is just the size it is output to the CDN that is important.

Comment: I just started working on this issue about two weeks ago, but my PM says that he noticed the pink stripe in the beginning of February. We already talked to shopify, but they didn't see any problem on their end and couldn't recreate the Issue. They advised us to contact our theme creator, but we ruled out that the issue comes from our theme. Also we noticed that the pink stripe doesn't appear in every PNG. Sometimes when we Upload a PNG it has the stripe, sometimes not. Please let me know if you find out more, I'll do the same!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).